# jQuery.post() Using serialized form data, and custom object in submission

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

When doing ajax stuff with jQuery you can pass your data along to the server in two key ways:

1. Use an object like

   ```
   {
    firstname:'blah',
    lastname: 'derp'
   }
   ```
2. Use a string like `&firstname=blah&lastname=derp`

(1) Arises naturally when you're passing in values programmatically.

(2) Arises naturally when you've got input fields.

My problem: it doesn't look like you can combine them, i.e.

```
jQuery.extend({
 firstname:'blah',
 lastname:'derp'
},jQuery('form.some-form').serialize());
```

And it's been nagging me for a while.

Truthfully I think they just need an objectified version of the serialize method that just gives you a json representation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920294/jquery-serialize-and-post

Answer (score 1):

This previous discussion should solve the problem of converting from json to a query string, and vice-versa:

[How can I convert query string or JSON object map to single JSON object with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789755/how-can-i-convert-query-string-or-json-object-map-to-single-json-object-with-jque)

Also, you might want to have a look at the [jQuery Form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)