# jQuery Post: Appending data to post

Tags: jquery, post

I'm using jQuery's post on a WordPress page.

```
var thename = jQuery("input#name").val();
    jQuery.post(the_ajax_script.ajaxurl, jQuery("#theForm").serialize(),
    function(response_from_the_action_function){
    jQuery("#response_area").html(response_from_the_action_function);
});
```

It posts the selections made in a form. Is it possible to append data to a post. So in addition to the form data, I need a couple lat longs added to the jQuery post. How can I do that. Is it possible?

Thnak you.

-Laxmidi

Comment: Not really 100% confident on what you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: Could you add the lat longs as hidden inputs in `#theForm`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920294/jquery-serialize-and-post

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.post()` takes a string as the second argument, so you can concatenate a custom string using `+` followed by your string.

```
var thename = jQuery("input#name").val();
    jQuery.post(the_ajax_script.ajaxurl, jQuery("#theForm").serialize() + "&foo=bar",
    function(response_from_the_action_function){
    jQuery("#response_area").html(response_from_the_action_function);
});
```

Do be careful, though; the string has to be correctly formatted as a URL, so you need `key=value` pairs separated by `&`s.

In the example above, you'll see `+ "&foo=bar`. The first `&` finishes the last value created by `.serialize()`, then `foo=` is a key, followed by `bar` as the value.

If you want to add more values afterwards, you can do something like  this:

```
&foo=bar&baz=zip
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var thename = jQuery("input#name").val();
var data = {'anycolortoulike':'transparent'}; // any data;
jQuery.post(the_ajax_script.ajaxurl, data.concat(jQuery("#theForm").serializeArray()),
    function(response_from_the_action_function){
       jQuery("#response_area").html(response_from_the_action_function);
    }
);
```

try this, `$.post` **can** use arrays