# Submit form with jquery plug-ins

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to submit the form with jquery. I am using bootstrap modal window. Here is a [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DHZNv/111/). Am i missing something? thanks alot

Update: I am trying to submit the form using ajax.
I also tried but not luck.

```
$('#comment_form').on('submit', function(){

  $.post("/yourReceivingPage", $(this).serialize(), function(){

  // Hide the modal
    $("#my-modal").modal('hide');

  });

  // Stop the normal form submission
  return false;
});
```

Comment: what is the name of php page that you're referring too? `/yourReceivingPage` ? Do you get any other errors from firebug? do you have any other frameworks on you page such as prototype?

Comment: can you show me what do you send to the .php file what string generated when you hit post? Try to get that sting with `alert()` there might be something wrong going after `.serialize()`

Comment: I think I have found you the answer, please check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920294/jquery-serialize-and-post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You refer to the wrong element, I have a working example for you, please check and let me know if it works for you:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#comment-form-submit').click(function() {
        $('#comment_form').submit();
        alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
        return false;
    });
});​
```

[jsFiddle Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rostovtsev/7SUTp/)

And for AJAX solution you need to refer to familiar and already discussed issue:

[jquery serialize and $.post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920294/jquery-serialize-and-post)

Edited: Referring to your question about how to extract the ID of the clickable link, this code will do it for you:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".comments.no").mouseover(function() {
     myDivsId = this.id;  // as you mouse over on the link it will be stored in Global Var and then transferred anywhere you wish.
   });
     $('#comment-form-submit').click(function() {
       $('#comment_form').submit();
       alert('Handler for .submit() called + div\'s ID = ' + myDivsId);
       return false;
   });
```

});​

[jsFiddle live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rostovtsev/qGE2C/)

Comment: hmmm. remember you're not alone! :) please read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046008/jsonp-request-returning-error-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token

Comment: An "unexpected token" is most likely unsupported character code. You need to debug the request string and make sure it's valid: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143698/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token

Comment: Ilia Rostovtsev thanks Can i alert `id` from `<div data-toggle="modal" href="#comment-form-modal" id="23"  href="#"  class="comments no">Click here 1</div>`. Is it possible? http://jsfiddle.net/7SUTp/1/

Comment: You are very welcome! If I got you right, is this what you need? http://jsfiddle.net/rostovtsev/gg6M8/

Comment: if you on `click here 2`. I will get same id. It should be `24`

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for just [submit().](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) What you are doing in your example is creating a function that will be run when the form is submitted. Also you are not setting up the handler for the clicking to submit the form.

```
// This creates submit handler for the form
$('#comment_form').submit(function() {
    alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
    return false;
});​

// This creates the on click handler for the submit button
$('#comment-form-submit').on('click', function() {
    // This actually submits the form
    $('#comment_form').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a click event for comment-form-submit button.

```
$(document).on('click','#comment-form-submit', function() {
    $('#comment_form').submit(function() {
       alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
       return false;
    });​
});
```